# use spring-data-r2dbc, Unable to inject DAO interface,Field myDao in ServiceImpl required a bean of type 'UmsAddressDao' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, r2dbc

1.illustrate

springboot 2.3.7
springboot-data-r2dbc 1.1.6

2.I used Spring-Data-R2DBC to operate mysql, but I have been reporting an errororg.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

3.Complete error description

```java
 cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webFluxController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'umsAddressService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'umsAddressServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'umsAddressDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.inner.UmsAddressDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


Field umsAddressDao in com.xxx.impl.UmsAddressServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.xxx.inner.UmsAddressDao' that could not be found.
```

3.My code snippet

my controller

```java
    @RestController
    public class WebFluxController {
    
        private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebFluxController.class);
    
        @Autowired
        private UmsAddressService umsAddressService;
    
        @Autowired
        private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;
    
        @Autowired
        private QuestionService questionService;
        // do something

    }
```

my service

```java
  
  
public interface UmsAddressService {
    Mono<UmsAddress> findById(Long id);
}
```

my service impl

```java
    @Service
    public class UmsAddressServiceImpl implements UmsAddressService {
    
        @Autowired
        private UmsAddressDao umsAddressDao;
    
        @Override
        public Mono<UmsAddress> findById(Long id) {
            return umsAddressDao.findById(id);
        }
    }
```

my dao

```java
   @Component
   public interface UmsAddressDao extends ReactiveCrudRepository<UmsAddress,Long> {
   
   }
```

my model

```java
    
    @Data
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @ToString
    @Table("ums_address")
    public class UmsAddress {
    
    
        @Id
        @Column("id")
        private Long id;
      
        @Column("member_id")
        private Long memberId;
    
      // other field
    
    }
```

springbootApplication

```java
    
    
    @EnableWebFlux
    @SpringBootApplication( exclude = { RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
    @OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "APIs", version = "1.0", description = "Documentation APIs v1.0"))
    public class MyWebApplication {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(RollkingWebApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE).run(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you configured your R2DBC connection?

Comment: The R2DBC has been configured with the MySQL connection, which can be connected to MySQL

Comment: Cause your error message tells us its not